# How to include version with sbt-native-packager publish?

Tags: scala, zip, sbt, nexus, sbt-native-packager

I'm currently using `sbt publish` to publish the jar etc to a Nexus repo but I also want to include the `zip`. I've tried using `sbt universal:publish` from the `sbt-native-packager` and this is creating the `zip` and `tgz` that I want but is putting them in a different place to the output from `sbt publish`

The `sbt publish` command places the files in a `PROJECT-NAME_2.11/PROJECT-NAME_2.11-999-SNAPSHOT.jar` whereas `sbt universal:publish` puts them in `PROJECT-NAME/PROJECT-NAME_2.11-999-SNAPSHOT.zip`. There is no scala version which means they sit in different directories.

How can I get these two commands to create their respective file in the same directory? Or is there another command I can use to get the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the scala version when you use `sbt publish` defining:

```
crossPaths := false
```

You can find more configuration examples [in this link](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Basic-Def-Examples.html).